# Laravel how to make eloquent fail safe

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have many to many relationship and I should be able to switch one to another.

The way I implement is

```
Model->detach([12,32,43],false)
Model->sync([12,32,43],false)
```

Lets say detach was successful but sync failed
Then I will lost original data .. How should I deal with this ? 
Is there any good way to prevent that ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to detach as `sync()` will detach all keys that are not present in the array, and attach all the given keys.

See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) part of the documentation.